# How to filter array with conditions array

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 arrays. In 1 array I have virtual machines with properties. In the other array I have property values. I want to iterate over the 1st array and filter out the elements with the property values from the 2nd array. But when I start to filter it, the following happens:

I start the iteration of the 1st array. For every element of the first array I iterate over every element in the second and I compare the values, but it doesn't work, because it is taking the values from the 2nd array consequentially and I need them with logical and (&&).

```
for (VirtualMachine vm: VmArray) {
            listOfVirtualMachinesToBuild.forEach(
                    vmFilter-> {
                        if (vmFilter.getType().equals(vm.getType())) {
                            Optional<DslModel.DiscoverIf[]> discoverIfOptional =
                                    Optional.ofNullable(vmFilter.getDiscoverIf());
                            if (discoverIfOptional.isPresent()) 
                               for (int i = 0; i < vmFilter.getDiscoverIf().length; i++) {
                                    if (vm.getProperty(
                                            vmFilter.getDiscoverIf()[i].getCondition())
                                            .equals(vmFilter.getDiscoverIf()[i].getValue())) {
                                        specificEntitiesToBuild.add(vm);
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                specificEntitiesToBuild.add(vm);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Do you have any ideas how?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I added code

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Stream API. I will demonstrate with `String`s but the same will work for any class:

```
String[] strings = {"a", "b", "c"};
Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(strings);
String[] filtered = stream.filter(s -> s.equals("a")).toArray(String[]::new);
```

If you want to check if a `String` is contained in a `String[]` (to lookup "properties"), as I think your intention is, you can do:

```
public boolean propertyExists(String property) {
    return Arrays.stream(propertyArray).anyMatch(s -> s.equals(property));
}
```

It is slightly unclear what you are asking, so this is my best guess. If you edit your question to show your actual code, it will be easier to help.